# Quarkus Kafka in cli mode

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus

I would like to create a Quarkus app in CLI mode to fetch data from kafka and store it in batch in the DB (as a Poor man's Spark).
Is it possible to somehow inject a Kafka consumer and manually decide (according to offset lag) to fetch the messages ?

Thnx

Comment: Ideally, you'd use Kafka Connect for this, but I'm not understanding what you mean by "manually decide," given that the SmallRye library will constantly poll messages from Kafka

Answer (score 1):

"bare-kafka" usage docs in CR:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/pull/746/